# Angular How to add text on top of mat-icon

Tags: html, css, angular, icons, mat

consider this html:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<mat-icon class="fa fa-folder" style="font-size:48px;"><span style="color: red; font-size: 30px">P</span></mat-icon>
```

Which result in Folder *icon* and P *text* next to it.

Is it possible to have the P *text* on top of Folder *icon*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
      <mat-icon class="fa fa-folder" style="font-size:40px; color: black">
      <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px; margin-right: 12px; display:block; margin-top: -35px; margin-left: 10px">P</span>
      </mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```html
    <mat-icon class="fa fa-folder" style="font-size:48px;"></mat-icon>
<div style="color: red; font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; margin-top:-1px; margin-left:15px">P</div>
```

Comment: not exactly what i'm looking for... I need the text to be inside the icon and to be aligned center according to it